# how to use validator in mongoose for checking a field to have isAlphanumeric and space

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose

I want to make sure if a field in the model, only have Alphanumeric and space.
I'm using validator.js in the mongoose.

this is what i tried but does not accept space in the field.

```
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'A product must have a Title Bro...'],
    trim: true,
    validate: [validator.isAlphanumeric, 'only characters are accepted'],
    maxlength: [50, 'the title must have less or equal than 50 characters'],
    minlength: [5, 'the title must have more or equal than 5 characters']

  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In Mongoose, you can use the built-in validators to validate fields in your schema. To achieve your requirement of checking whether a field contains alphanumeric characters and spaces, you can use the match validator with a regular expression. Here's how you can do it:

Assuming you have a schema for a model named User, and you want to validate the username field to contain only alphanumeric characters and spaces, here's an example of how you can define your schema using Mongoose:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    match: /^[A-Za-z0-9\s]+$/, // Regular expression to allow alphanumeric characters and spaces
  },
  // other fields...
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but I wonder if i can use validator.js library to solve this problem. and one more thing is that, in your solution I don't see any custom validator!!! is match the validator here?